# Keys on laptop keypad are mistyped 

Tags: laptop

Am having a dell c60 laptop as a old scrap. Recently i made it serviced and now its working.
But the problem is that three keys are misprinting when typed them. eg:when i type the key k it prints as "ghyi+" . What would be the problem might be???

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution is just as simple as [Cleaning the Laptop Keyboard](http://www.computing.net/howto/simple/keyboard/).

To rule out software issues, connect an external keyboard, if that works fine, then it's most likely a hardware problem that can solved with a bit of cleaning or a keyboard replacement.

Comment: Although that being my first thought as well ... "ghy" okey, but "i" and "+" are not so close any more ...

Comment: @ldigas: I've seen a keyboard type "qwer mesd+du=querio!" when the 2 key was pressed.

The circuits were a little damaged and the keyboard was scrapped.

Answer (score 1):

If Molly's answer doesn't work, the keyboard has a cut trace or corrosion, or the keyboard logic controller is damaged. Beyond cleaning your only option is a replacement keyboard.